# Use try_files to redirect /dir1 to /dir2 in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have some part of the websites still using old urls.

Essentially, I want:

`http://hostname/app1/static/dir1` --> `http://hostname/app1/static/dir2`.

The `static` directory may contain other resources which are being used.

I tried the following but I am getting cycle which caused nginx to abort:

```
location ^~ /app1/static/  {
    alias /home/app1_user/app1/static/;
    try_files /app1/static/dir1 /app1/static/dir2;
}
```

What should I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it would be -

A file, e.g. `/app1/static/file.jpg` will `try_files` in `/home/app1_user/app1/dir1/file.jpg`, `/home/app1_user/app1/dir2/file.jpg` and lastly 404 if it can't be found.

```
location ~ ^/app1/static/(.*)$ {
    alias /home/app1_user/app1/static/;
    try_files dir1/$1 dir2/$1 =404;
}
```